# Use .htaccess to cease processing if particular string is captured in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need the following .htaccess file to redirect requests for pages ending in `njiswebhook` to `\webhooklanding.php`.

At the moment the requests are still being passed to `index.php` and are being routed by [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com).  How can I tell .htaccess to cease processing if a particular condition is met?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*njiswebhook /webhooklanding.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[END]` flag stopped processing upon reaching that clause.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*njiswebhook /webhooklanding.php [QSA,L,END]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The above solution has been implemented and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Make an exception from last rule , otherwise nothing will pass to  `webhooklanding.php` like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*njiswebhook  webhooklanding.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule !^webhooklanding\.php index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found a solution which I will post below.  I will remove it if this method is deemed better or more appropriate.